# How to check if a computer in the network is down and then send a notification email?

Tags: notifications, network-monitoring

I need to check if a computer in the network is down. If this is true, I would like to send to myself a notification email. I have Windows 7. I was trying to do it with xStarter but I could not find the way to do it. If possible I would like to do it with xStarter but any other option would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. You know its IP and it will reply to your ping. Ping it. If you don't get the expected reply, send yourself a mail.
2. You know the IP, but it won't reply. You need to use other network resorces, if they are available.
3. You don't know the IP. But you know the MAC and your network offers MAC to IP resolution. Resolve it and go back to point 1.
4. You don't know the IP nor do you know the MAC. Here you need ninja skills.

Comment: Step 4. Hire a ninja to check in person?

Comment: That's one possibility.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, but this have to be done programmatically. I need a job running 24/7 that sends me an email in case a specific pc in the network (I know its IP) its down. Should I use a batch file with an infinite cycle? Or xStarter? Also the issue of sending an email is not easy, I did a search and the only one I have found is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094440/send-files-by-email-on-a-regular-basis-via-batch-file

Comment: I don't know what xStarter is. What OS do you use? Normally, you'd check every so often if the pc is on using an OS built in mechanism. Another way is to have the pc say farewell to you when it goes down. These both can work together. But for the latter one you need to be that pc's admin, or ask the user to wire-in a script doing this.

Comment: I am amministrator. And I use windows 7.

Comment: Just a Thought you could probably use this to monitor them. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d537e5c-b5d4-42ca-a23e-2cbce636f58d/